# Filename getting changed while downloading in IE 9 Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a report application. It features one report downloading section where we can download the reports in .csv format. The filename will be like "currentdate"_"currenttime".csv for e.g 07232013_060045PM.csv.

In Mozilla firefox the file is downloaded correctly. But in IE-9 the filename is getting changed to GeneratePDF.csv

When I analysed I found GeneratePDF as the servlet name. But I didn't get why the filename is getting changed so.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set properly filename in Content-Disposition HTTP response header

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=07232013_060045PM.csv
```

Comment: +1, I was about to make a near-identical answer. Although it would have helped if the OP had specified what methods he's using already to specify the filename.